# how to parse this into an array with PHP?

Tags: php, app-store

Apple's app store sends this object back as a receipt. I want to parse it into an array. What's the easiest way to do this?

```
{
    "signature" = "AlHSJDRPuOhUBrIarX84l/YeP+ZpxYyd592/oyF7MkVYb/s13L2W8ag2C+PG0wSHPthbv9dNMBsG4TGg3aP7r7N+oa9Rsp9C3Qu03Z9b7PRzYM2KGXHDmOMk7vDpeMVlLDPSGYz1+U3sDxJzebSpbaJmT7imzUKfggEY7xxf4czfH0yj5wNzSGTOvQ==";
    "purchase-info" = "ewoJIm9yaWdpbmFsLXB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUtcHN0IiA9ICIyMDE2LTAzLTIyIDEwOjUxOjAzIEFtZXJpY2EvTG9zX0Fucm9wYXRoLmZpcnN0IjsKCSJwdXJjaGFzZS1kYXRlLXBzdCIgP0wMy0yMiAxMDo1MTowMSBBbWVyaWNhL0xvc19BbmdlbGVzIjsKCSJxdWFudGl0eSIgPSAiMSI7Cn0=";
    "environment" = "Sandbox";
    "pod" = "100";
    "signing-status" = "0";
}
```

Please notice that it's not JSON, and json_decode does not work on it.

Comment: well. check what kind of format they are using. it looks like json. Maybe check if you can request json.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to parse it in to an array? It doesn't really contain any useful data. The main reason to use it is to pass straight back to Apple for verification. You don't need to extract any of the data at all.

Comment: @Ciccio The document you provided specifically says you don't need to decode it to verify it though. You just need to base64 encode it, put it in a JSON object and send it to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another quick example which may be a little easier to read for those not used to regular expressions:

```
$response = '{
"signature" = "AlHSJDRPuOhUBrIarX84l/YeP+ZpxYyd592/oyF7MkVYb/s13L2W8ag2C+PG0wSHPthbv9dNMBsG4TGg3aP7r7N+oa9Rsp9C3Qu03Z9b7PRzYM2KGXHDmOMk7vDpeMVlLDPSGYz1+U3sDxJzebSpbaJmT7imzUKfggEY7xxf4czfH0yj5wNzSGTOvQ==";
"purchase-info" = "ewoJIm9yaWdpbmFsLXB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUtcHN0IiA9ICIyMDE2LTAzLTIyIDEwOjUxOjAzIEFtZXJpY2EvTG9zX0Fucm9wYXRoLmZpcnN0IjsKCSJwdXJjaGFzZS1kYXRlLXBzdCIgP0wMy0yMiAxMDo1MTowMSBBbWVyaWNhL0xvc19BbmdlbGVzIjsKCSJxdWFudGl0eSIgPSAiMSI7Cn0=";
"environment" = "Sandbox";
"pod" = "100";
"signing-status" = "0";
}';

$response = trim(str_replace(array('{', '}', '"', '    ', ';'), '', $response));
$responseLines = explode("\n", $response);

$result = array();
foreach ($responseLines as $responseLine) {
    $lineElements = explode(" = ", $responseLine);
    $result[$lineElements[0]] = $lineElements[1];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: This isn't reliable as the 'value' can contain `=`, so they are missing after exploding.